# How to correctly close BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, buffer, bufferedreader, filereader

I've this code for reading a JSON file:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    JsonObject data = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, JsonObject.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "DATA: " + data.toString());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code seems to work fine, but in logcat I receive these 3 lines:

```
com.example.package W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
com.example.package W/System: A resource failed to call end. 
com.example.package W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Is it normal or am I doing something wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just use a `try` with resource like `try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) { ... }` to get rid of the `finally` block? You will have to add a `catch` clause for an `IOException` in that case...

Comment: @fantaghirocco `BufferedReader` seems to be closing the underlying input as per [source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/java/io/BufferedReader.java#531). I'm not sure how OP's code is failing to close stuff.

Comment: There is no evidence here that the errors are coming from this code. The suggestion to use try-with-resources changes nothing. It's just a shorthand for what the OP already wrote. @deHaar

Answer (score -2):

Ok, @deHaar, was right:

```
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    JsonObject data = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, JsonObject.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "DATA: " + data.toString());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This way I'm not getting the warnings. But I didn't understand why. If anyone could write it in comments, I'll appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: This is fully equivalent to what you already wrote. Clearly the problem was elsewhere and you fixed it without knowing it.

Comment: Well I thinks something big has changed, I've no more finally section with close method...

Comment: But you never had any evidence that the problem was coming from here in the first place. What you wrote and what you now write are 100% equivalent. This new code is just a shorthand for the old code.

Comment: @user207421 Doesn't the fact that the warnings don't come up when using this code as evidence? Maybe, maybe not... However, it must have had something to do with resource management and obviously, the `try` with resources could improve something, although we don't really know what exactly.

Comment: No.What is obvious when you read the specification of try-with-resources is that its execution is identical to what you originally coded. *Ergo* you changed something else to fix it.